# Are links within SlideShare presentations indexed by search engines?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, backlinks, pdf

I have created a PDF presentation including links to a site I own on the last slide. So far, such links are not reported in Google Webmaster Tools. When I search Google for the presentation, I can find it. It is indexed.

I know GWT can be slow at detecting backlinks, but should I expect those links to be reported in GWT? Would they be reported as SlideShare backlinks? Or not? Has anyone noticed such backlinks in their link profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this google article say linksin pdfs are crawled and can not be no followed
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/pdfs-in-google-search-results.html

Answer (score 1):

GWT backlinks report is not the one to trust too, I think. It may show links from deindexed pages, and do not show the live ones.
To check the backlinks use ahrefs or something. GWT is only an additional tool to see.
Regarding indexing by search engines, search for the exact text around the link/anchor (or with anchor) and see the results.

Answer (score 1):

[PDF files are crawled and indexed by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en).   Links in them do count as backlinks.    A few years ago there was a site that got a penalty for distributing PDF files for various websites to post because those files contained links with anchor text of popular search terms.

The site on this PDF file resides would have to allow the PDF to be crawled and not  nofollow the links in it (for example with the [X-Robots-Tag header](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag)).

As Marian says, links may not show up in Google Webmaster Tools, even when Google does count those links.   Google says that the report there is a sample of the links to your site.